# How to mysqli_result::fetch_array with key [table.attribute] in the array?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

I'm trying to create a general method to automatically instantiate objects from a query like this:

```
SELECT town.*, content.*, user.*
FROM townhub.content
LEFT JOIN town ON content.townReceiver = town.id_town
LEFT JOIN user ON content.author = user.id_user
```

The method that I want to build should return 3 type of objects: `Town`, `User` and `Content` into an array.  I thought on something like that:

```
protected function build_objects($result, Array $classes) {
    $data = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        foreach ($classes as $class) {
            $$class = new $class;
            $$class = $$class->fill_object($$class, $row);
            $data[$i][$class] = $$class;


        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

And then, in each class, a method like that:

```
public function fill_object($object, Array $row) {
    $attributes = get_object_vars($object);
    foreach ($row as $attribute => $value) {
        foreach ($attributes as $objAtt => $emptyValue) {
            if ($attribute == $objAtt) {
                $object->$attribute = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $object;
}
```

Actually, this is doing what I want, the following array (was printed using using var_dump($data) in `build_objects()` ):

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'Content' => 
        object(Content)[4]
          protected 'id_content' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'title' => string 'Hello World!' (length=10)
          public 'description' => string 'Hello world description' (length=43)
          public 'category' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'date' => string '2015-01-01' (length=10)
          public 'townReceiver' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'author' => string '1' (length=1)
          private 'dbHost' (Model) => string 'localhost' (length=9)
          private 'dbUser' (Model) => string 'root' (length=4)
          private 'dbPass' (Model) => string 'root' (length=4)
          private 'dbName' (Model) => string 'townhub' (length=7)
          private 'conn' (Model) => null
      'Town' => 
        object(Town)[5]
          protected 'id_town' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'name' => string 'Isaac' (length=5)
          public 'population' => string '750' (length=3)
          private 'dbHost' (Model) => string 'localhost' (length=9)
          private 'dbUser' (Model) => string 'root' (length=4)
          private 'dbPass' (Model) => string 'root' (length=4)
          private 'dbName' (Model) => string 'townhub' (length=7)
          private 'conn' (Model) => null
      'User' => 
        object(User)[6]
          protected 'id_user' => string '1' (length=1)
          protected 'dni' => string '20011225' (length=9)
          private 'password' => string '1234' (length=4)
          public 'name' => string 'Isaac' (length=5)
          public 'firstSurname' => string 'Surname1' (length=5)
          public 'secondSurname' => string 'Surname2' (length=5)
          public 'birthdate' => string '0000-00-00' (length=10)
          public 'gender' => string 'H' (length=1)
          public 'email' => string 'isaac@mail.com' (length=19)
          public 'isAdmin' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'id_town' => string '1' (length=1)
          private 'dbHost' (Model) => string 'localhost' (length=9)
          private 'dbUser' (Model) => string 'root' (length=4)
          private 'dbPass' (Model) => string 'root' (length=4)
          private 'dbName' (Model) => string 'townhub' (length=7)
          private 'conn' (Model) => null
```

The problem is that when I fech_array (in `fill_object()` method) town's names are overridden by user's names; so I can't get the town's name. The easy solution is to change attribute's names on db and classes; but I think that will be a bad solution...
Keep in mind that attribute's names should be equals on db and classes, so `alias` in the query is not possible.

**There are any way to get with `fetch_array` an Array with key [table.attribute] instead [attribute]?**
I would also like to know better ways to do this if what I want to do is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php

class DataCollectionHelper
{
    /**
     * $result var is the result of:
     * "SELECT *
     * FROM townhub.content".
     * 
     * As you left join your tables, it may appear that you haven't any towns and users
     * for particular content.
     *
     * @param $result
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    protected function build_objects($result)
    {
        $data = array();
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $contentObject = new Content();
            $contentObject->fill_object($row);
            $data[$i]['Content'] = $contentObject;
            $data[$i]['User'] = $this->getUserByContentAuthor($contentObject->getAuthor());
            $data[$i]['Town'] = $this->getTownByContentByTownReceiver($contentObject->getTownReceiver());
            $i++;
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $townReceiver
     *
     * @return Town
     */
    private function getTownByContentByTownReceiver($townReceiver)
    {
        /**
         * Here you have to get town data by your $townReceiver - property
         *  and return the object of Town
         */
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $author
     *
     * @return User
     */
    private function getUserByContentAuthor($author)
    {
        /**
         * The same here for users
         */
    }
}

class Content
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $content_id;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $title;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    public $townReceiver;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $description;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    public $author;
    /* other vars */

    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function fill_object(array $row)
    {
        /*
         * It's not the best approach, to do like that.
         * It's better to use setters or just set your properties
         * $this->title = $row['title']; etc
         *
         * Still you could use $this instead of your $object variable
         */
        $attributes = get_object_vars($this);
        foreach ($row as $attribute => $value) {

            foreach ($attributes as $objAtt => $emptyValue) {
                if ($attribute == $objAtt) {
                    $this->$attribute = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getTownReceiver()
    {
        return $this->townReceiver;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I agree with you, that my `fill_object` it's not the best approach, but for the moment, I will keep it, because it's working.

About your sollution, it's working, but the problem is that will make too many queries to the database. I'm working on another sollution that I will post it when completed. Thank you :)

Comment: Hey, glad you've finally took a loot at it :). It's an approach for you at this moment. Yeah, it this's about some additional sql queries, but it's would be easier to work with if you would decide  to add some additional objects. Take a look at Doctrine ORM, you will be impressed by it, I promise. And maybe my work deserves upvote at least?;)

Comment: I already know Doctrine ORM, I'm working as Symfony 2 developer, and it's really powerful, but for this time, I prefer to write the entire code; I don't like to depend always on frameworks ;-) And of couse, your upvote! haha

Comment: So, is it your try to reinvent your own ORM? Good luck if it's so!:) Frameworks are just tools, and usually open-source tools, so you can contribute as well. But it's up to you of course.